# How to split bridge table into two tables in EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a requirement where I have slip the bridge table into tables for storing more info about the many to many relationship. So "idea" is that the ComputerUser table becomes two tables and reference that way so that more info can be stored in of these two bridge tables other than just many to many relationship references. Thank you for your insights Following is what I have so :

```
public  class Computer
{

[Key]
    public Guid ComputerId { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public string ClientVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivity { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    public Setting Settings { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } 
    public bool? ResetRequested { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<ScanEvent> Scans { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EventLog> Logs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ComputerUser> UserLinks { get; set; }
    }
public class ComputerUser
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid ComputerId { get; set; }
    public  Computer Computer { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public Guid  UserId { get; set; }
    public  User User { get; set; }

}

    public class User
 {
    [Key]

   public Guid   UserId { get; set; } 
   public  string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
   public DateTime Updated { get; set; } 
   public Setting Setting { get; set; } 
   public long SerialNumber { get; set; } 
   public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Credential> Credentials { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ComputerUser> ComputerLinks { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: is it possible to divide ComputerUser in two tables

Comment: You may want to update your post to properly state the question.  Your 'bridge' or many-to-many table can have extra columns added to it.  As long as EF can figure out the relationships using the keys (which it already does) then you can add all the extra properties you need to the `ComputerUser` class.  There's no need to split the table to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

All you're talking about is a M2M with a payload (i.e. additional information besides just the relationship itself). The only requirement for that is a using an actual entity class for your relationship, which you're *already* doing with `ComputerUser`. Simply add additional properties as necessary to that entity.

Comment: the requirement has changed as follows : Split the ComputerUser table into two tables, ComputerUserAuthorization and ComputerUserAudit. Add a datetime field to the latter to track most recent user logon. (Optionally, add a bit field to the Computers table to determine whether the contents of the ComputerUserAuthorization table are a whitelist or a blacklist.)